# Javascript RegExp non-capturing groups : Do you really need non-capturing group (?:) for date format (mm/yy)? Does general group () work?

Tags: regex

expirationDateValidRegex: /^(?:0|([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2]{1})?(?:/ -)?)$/

Comment: Optimization: `[0]?` -> `0?`

Comment: Optimization: `[0-2]{1}` -> `[0-2]`